# Java Timer with timeout capability

Tags: java, timer

I am implementing a timer:

```
timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do something;
                }
            },1000,1000);
```

But, I would like to have a timeout so that after lets say 100 tries/ 10 seconds, the timer stops automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: You can schedule `timer.cancel()` after 10 seconds.

Comment: @assylias `Timer` should be a long-lived singleton. OP should cancel the task only.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You are right, it should be `task.cancel()`.

Comment: [here](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/01/timer.html) is the complete tutorial about timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int n = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(n);
            if (++n == 5) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    },1000,1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply have a variable outside the run method that keeps count of the iteration. Make an `if` statement inside the `run()` method that cancels the timer when it hits your desired amount. Increase the variable by one everytime the `run()` method executes.

Comment: could you please provide and exmaple

Answer (score 0):

start another timer, as soon as above timer starts, which cancels the above timer after 10sec. check to code below as a quick solution. but better you cancel the task() instead of timer.

```
timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timer2.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        timer1.cancel();
                    }
            },0);
                    //Do something;
                }
            },1000,1000);

timer2 = new Timer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think we have java API for this in Timer class. You need to do it programmatically by implementing some custom logic based on your requirement.